# delete value from input when uncheck the checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have checkbox with input fields. When checkbox is clicked then related input field opens and type some text in input. But when I uncheck the checkbox then text from related input should be blank.

```
<?php 
  $result = $obj->show_social_icons();
  foreach($result as $row)
   {
?>
  <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

  <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
  <div class="max_tickets">
    <input type="text" name="link[]" class="link">
  </div>
  <br>
<?php } ?>
```

**My jquery is:**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('input.maxtickets_enable_cb').change(function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
$(this).next('.max_tickets').show();
else
$(this).next('.max_tickets').hide();
}).change();
});
```

When I uncheck the checkbox then related input filed should be blank or erase. It is not happening. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry could not use `PHP`. So example is just in `HTML` and `jQuery`.

You were hiding the parent `div` of `input` but not emptying it.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input.maxtickets_enable_cb').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      $(this).next('.max_tickets').show();
    else
      $(this).next('.max_tickets').hide().children('input').val('');
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[]" value="1">
<div class="max_tickets">
  <input type="text" name="link[]" class="link">
</div>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[]" value="2">
<div class="max_tickets">
  <input type="text" name="link[]" class="link">
</div>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[]" value="3">
<div class="max_tickets">
  <input type="text" name="link[]" class="link">
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the value from an `input` use `val('')`. Also, `next()` doesn't work in this case as the elements are not siblings; you `echo` a text node between them. To fix this you could wrap each looped block in a `div` and use a combination of `closest()` and `find()`.

Also note that you can simplify the `show()`/`hide()` logic to use `toggle()` instead, providing the `checked` property as the boolean argument which determines whether the content should be made visible or not.

Finally, use `label` elements to enable the user to click the text by the checkbox in order to check it.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('input.maxtickets_enable_cb').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.max_tickets').toggle(this.checked).find('input').val('');
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.max_tickets { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[]" value="id1" /> 
    Name #1
  </label>
  <div class="max_tickets">
    <input type="text" name="link[]" class="link">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" name="opwp_wootickets[]" value="id2" /> 
    Name #2
  </label>
  <div class="max_tickets">
    <input type="text" name="link[]" class="link">
  </div>
</div>
```